# Not appending to a list correctly?

Tags: python

```
def addItem():
    flavorsMenu()
    flavor = int(input("> "))
    validateData(flavor)
    if validateData(flavor) == "f":
        print("Sorry, that was an invalid choice.")
        return None
    else:
        print("How many would you like to buy? (1-10) ")
        qty = int(input("> "))
        if qty <= 0 or qty > 10:
            print("Invalid number, please try again")
        else:
            quantityList.append(qty)
            itemsList.append(flavors[flavor - 1])
            print("You have added", qty, str(flavors[flavor - 1]) + "(s) to your list.")
            return flavor
```

I put the return flavor to see if it would help, but it didn't, I have everything defined at the top in

```
flavors = ["Thin Mints", "Tagalongs", "Samoas", "Lemon Chalet Cremes", "Dulce de Leche", "Sugar Free Chocolate Chip", "Do-Si-Dos", "Trefoil"]
```

But when I input 5, it gives me thin mints which is 1. When I enter 4, it gives me thin mints again. When I input 3, it gives me tagalongs.

Why is this happening?

Comment: its only a guess but can you print the flavor list at the end to verify it actually contains what you think it has, as i can't see nothing wrong with the code

Comment: @Srgrn ['Thin Mints', 'Tagalongs', 'Samoas', 'Lemon Chalet Cremes', 'Dulce de Leche', 'Sugar Free Chocolate Chip', 'Do-Si-Dos', 'Trefoil'] is what it prints out when I do "print(flavors)"

Comment: weird i have rewrote it and it works fine for me

Comment: Also try `print(flavor-1)` right after the `else:`

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; there is no way to recreate the issue from the code posted. You should also read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote your code as:

```
flavors = ["Thin Mints", "Tagalongs", "Samoas", "Lemon Chalet Cremes", "Dulce de Leche", "Sugar Free Chocolate Chip", "Do-Si-Dos", "Trefoil"]

quantityList = []
itemsList = []

def addItem():
    flavor = int(input("> "))
    print("How many would you like to buy? (1-10) ")
    qty = int(input("> "))
    if qty <= 0 or qty > 10:
        print("Invalid number, please try again")
    else:
        quantityList.append(qty)
        itemsList.append(flavors[flavor - 1])
        print("You have added", qty, str(flavors[flavor - 1]) + "(s) to your list.")
        return flavor

print flavors[ addItem() -1 ]
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Found out the problem with my code, it was actually in my showOrder function, it was printing 

    "flavor[c]" 
in a 
    for c in range(len(itemsList)) 

function

Comment: I'm having another problem.

The problem was in my show menu function, but when I attempt to print out the 

    str(flavors([addItem()-1]))

it doesn't work in the function. Why is this? Do I need to reference it as global?

Comment: shouldn't it be str(flavors[addItem()-1]) ??
also why are you converting it to string? if its a string it should be fine to the best of my knowledge